# update-rc.d on raspberrypi can not start service automatically on reboot

Tags: raspberry-pi, yocto, auto-update, openembedded

I have created x11 yocto (openembedded) build for raspberry pi 3.
I want my QT application to launch at boot time.
What I have already done is as follows

```
1- created a launch script (acess_service) and placed it in /etc/init.d location (with 755 permissions)
2- executed update-rc.d access_service defaults
3- This step has created links of my service file in all /etc/rcX.d folders
4- I can launch the script to start and stop from terminal
```

like `/etc/init.d/access_service start` and stop and my graphical application launches successfully.
Now the problem is, when I reboot my PC it never starts automatically. I just see the terminal.

I have also tried, couple of other options like adding the launch script to inittab or profile
none of the option seem to be working for auto launching application.
Can anyone help int this?

Comment: Are you sure you use `sysvinit` as Init manager and not `systemd`? (see `ls -l /sbin/init`)

Comment: /sbin/init -> /sbin/init.sysvinit

Comment: Does your QT application is added to Yocto image with a recipe? If so, did you add something like `inherit update-rc.d`  `INITSCRIPT_NAME = "<qtappname>"`  `INITSCRIPT_PARAMS = "defaults 10"`

Comment: Actually that was the first step I tried, when i didn't work I tried checking that manually on board.

Comment: If you can share your recipe, it will help resolving your problem.